# What is the difference between ('a * 'a) list and 'a * 'a list in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to delcare a list of type `string * string list` (whose type is required in other functions), and I keep getting type mismatch errors. If I were to define a list as
`let a = [("a" , "b")]`,
I get an error when I pass it into a function that expects type `string * string list`:

```
Error: This expression has type (string * string) list
       but an expression was expected of type string * string list
```

The same error occurs when a declare it as `let a = ["a" , "b"]`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misreading the type: type application binds tighter than product, thus

```ml
string * string list
```

means

```ml
string * (string list)
```

For example:

```ml
let x: string * string list = "a", ["b"]
```

compared to

```ml
let y : (string * string) list = ["a", "b"; "c", "d"]
```

Comment: I think the last one is correct, the writeup for my homework says my output should look something like`[ ("crooner", "conqueror"); ("italy", "quality"); ("stir", "squirt"); ("teens", "sequent")]. `
But the type for the output in the writeup for the function is `string * string list`.

Comment: Perhaps a typo in the writeup's type? The sample output given is of type `(string * string) list` and not `string * string list`.

Comment: Thanks, probably a typo. I have another error happening in the program: I have `(a, a2)::rest of the list` where `a` and `a2` are strings. But I'm getting an error where it now correctly expects `(string * string) list` (I changed the types to be correct) but the line is of type `string * string list`. Why is this happening? Should I ask this in a new post?

Comment: It is hard to tell without more context.

Answer (score 1):

An `('a * 'a) list` is a list of `('a * 'a)` tuples, while a `'a * 'a list` is a tuple of an `'a` with a list of `'a`.